# is there a tool for making graph paper style maps?

Tags: tool-recommendation, maps

Historically I have scanned my graph-paper maps into Photoshop Elements and cut them into pieces to include them in my campaign notes docs. This works fine, no problem.

Recently I have started using *Inkarnate* and (mainly) *Dungeondraft* for making maps for use in a VTT. It got me thinking - are there any utilities for making simple, monochrome, graph-paper style maps? There are some assets for *Dungeondraft* that would kind of work, but I think I'd stick with scanning hardcopy. Any suggestions?

Comment: I feel like this question is likely to be closed, because if I remember correctly "shopping" and recommendation-type questions aren't considered on-topic here, but if I'm understanding the question correctly I think I have a recommendation for you @Omortis, want to join me in chat? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/trpg-general-chat if this is the kind of thing you're looking for: http://prntscr.com/13kjgjo

Comment: No, you're right - I'm going to close it and ask on reddit. Thanks, though!